# return_url is not working for Stripe Identity Verification when used in an iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, identity, verification

I'm trying to integrate the Stripe identity verification in my app inside an iframe using the redirect method as mentioned in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/identity/verify-identity-documents?platform=web&type=redirect).

But after the verification document is submitted successfully, the 'Done' button does not call the URL mentioned in the `return_url` set while creating the verification session.

It does work when not done in an iframe. i.e redirects to the URL set in the `return_url` if done in a separate page

Iframe:
[image]

Is there a way to listen to the 'Done' button inside the iframe and call an API after it is clicked?

Code:

```
def verification_next
    verification_session = Stripe::Identity::VerificationSession.create(
      {
        type:       'document',
        metadata:   {
          user_id: current_user&.id,
        },
        options:{
          document: {
            require_matching_selfie: true
          }
        },
        return_url: "http://localhost:3000/?success"
      }
    )

    # Return only the client secret to the frontend
    @redirect_url = verification_session.url
  end
```

Comment: Are there any errors logged in the browser console? Also, maybe the Stripe page is not designed to work inside an iframe if using the 'redirect' mode, and instead they intend for the 'modal' mode to be used if you want to keep the experience on your page?

Comment: There are no errors in browser console. The button event is not triggered. 

You might be right about the Stripe redirect mode not designed to be used inside an iframe – it seems to work as intended outside of the iframe.
However, I do need it inside an iframe. Is there anyway we can listen to the onclick of the the Stripe's 'Done' button inside the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to adding an event listener to a component places in the iframe, here is how;

```
document.getElementById('frameID').contentDocument.body.addEventListener('mouseup', Handler);
```

Play with it and find the done button, maybe go with Xpath.

If you want something else, please explain it more in the question.